# Changing OpenGL Vertex Buffer Object data via pyopengl OpenGL.arrays.vbo has no effect

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, pyqt5, pyopengl

I am stuck trying to change data in a VBO.

I setup a scene with 2 Triangle primitives using a VBO via the python `OpenGL.arrays.vbo` helper class. That worked.

Then I want to change the data (in the minimal example below just shift one vertex when a button is clicked) which I cannot bring to work. I'm not sure if I use the VBO incorrectly or if there is some triviality blocking the redraw on the PyQt5 side.

Below is the full minimal example, the important stuff takes play in the member functions `initializeGL`, `paintGL`, and `shift`.

Inside `GLWidget.shift` I tried different approaches following the docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672720/pyopengl-dynamically-updating-values-in-a-vertex-buffer-object) without success. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes
import sys
import numpy as np
import OpenGL.arrays.vbo as glvbo

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QOpenGLWidget,
                             QWidget, QPushButton)

import OpenGL.GL as gl

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.glWidget = GLWidget()
        button = QPushButton('shift', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.glWidget.shift)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.glWidget)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.object = None

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(400, 400)

    def initializeGL(self):
        gl.glClearColor(0., 0., 0., 0.)

        # a red and a green triangle
        self.vertices = np.array([
            # <- x,y,z ----->  <- r,g,b -->
            -0.5, -0.2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, 0.5,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.4, -0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.4, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.4, 0.5,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        ], 'f')

        self.vbo = glvbo.VBO(self.vertices)
        self.vbo.bind()

        self.object = gl.glGenLists(1)

        gl.glNewList(self.object, gl.GL_COMPILE)

        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

        buffer_offset = ctypes.c_void_p
        stride = (3+3)*self.vertices.itemsize

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, stride, None)
        gl.glColorPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, stride, buffer_offset(12))

        gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

        gl.glEndList()
        gl.glShadeModel(gl.GL_FLAT)

    def paintGL(self):
        gl.glClear(
            gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        gl.glRotated(50.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        gl.glCallList(self.object)

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        side = min(width, height)
        if side < 0:
            return

        gl.glViewport((width - side) // 2, (height - side) // 2, side,
                           side)

        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        gl.glOrtho(-1., +1., -1., +1., -100.0, 100.0)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)

    def shift(self):
        # shift y-position of one vertex
        self.vertices[1] += 10.3
        assert self.vertices is self.vbo.data

        # version 1
        # self.vbo.implementation.glBufferSubData(self.vbo.target, 0, self.vbo.data)

        # version 2
        # self.vbo[:] = self.vertices[:]
        # self.vbo.bind()
        # self.vbo.copy_data()

        # version 2b (use slice)
        # self.vbo[1:2] = self.vertices[1:2]
        # self.vbo.bind()
        # self.vbo.copy_data()

        # version 3
        self.vbo.set_array(self.vertices)
        self.vbo.bind()
        self.vbo.copy_data()

        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code runs on an `Ubuntu 18.04` machine under `python 3.6` with

```
  Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
  Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
  OpenGL Version: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
  Shader Version: 1.30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sisplay lists ([`glGenList`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGenLists.xml)) are deprecated. What you try to encode in the list is the [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification).
I recommend to use a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) instead.

Create the VAO, before specifying the array of generic vertex attribute data:

```py
class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    # [...]

    def initializeGL(self):
        # [...]

        self.vbo = glvbo.VBO(self.vertices)
        self.vbo.bind()

        self.vao = gl.glGenVertexArrays(1)
        gl.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

        buffer_offset = ctypes.c_void_p
        stride = (3+3)*self.vertices.itemsize
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, stride, None)
        gl.glColorPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, stride, buffer_offset(12))

        gl.glBindVertexArray(0)
```

When you want to draw the object, then is sufficient to bind the VAO:

```py
class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    # [...]

    def paintGL(self):
        gl.glClear(
            gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        gl.glRotated(50.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        gl.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
        gl.glBindVertexArray(0)
```

---

Note, the display list does not work, because certain commands are not compiled into the display list but are executed immediately, including `glVertexPointer` and `glColorPointer`. See [`glNewList`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNewList.xml).

Comment: Thanks, Your example works. However, why would You still keep the `VBO`-instance, it shouldn't be necessary anymore, right? Originally my goal was to use VBOs, not VAOs, but Your hint solved my problem, so I accept this as an the answer.

Comment: Just to understand as much as possible from Your answer: Is there a reason why You suggest VAOs instead VBOs? This choice is independent of the important hint not to use display lists, right? I would assume that for a far larger dataset where only few vertices are updated VBOs should perform better, is that correct?

Comment: @flonk You need both, the vbo and the vao. The vbo is referenced by the vao. When `glVertexPointer` (etc.) is called, the the currently bound vbo is associated (for the specified attribute) in the state vector of the currently bound vao. The vao stores all the specifications which are necessray to draw the mesh, but it doesn't store the vertex data (it just reference the vertex data by the vbo). Thus it is sufficient to update the data in the vbo, without updating the vao.

Comment: I think using the `OpenGL.arrays.vbo`-Helper class I don't need to deal explicitly with the VAO, but can proceed with the commands as in my code after switching away from display lists. If You don't agree and are interested I could post the code (?)